# Deploy smartphone application on windows 7

Tags: c#, .net, windows-ce, smartphone

I'm working on a smartphone application, I test my application on an emulator and I cannot connect the real device to the pc I'm writing my application on. What I want is to deploy or publish application on the pc and then transfer the install package to the device and install it there, is this possible? If yes how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found my answer after a while.
I just needed to add a setup project to my application and then build the setup project which would give me a `.cab` file that can be installed on the smart device.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure on what platform you are working for your platform but if you are working on:

Windows phone you need Visual studio or Wp7 SDK to run your app on device or publish to market

Android, you need eclipse and Android SDK

iOS mac with xCode installed

let's say you have .apk file so you can install it in many way but the easy way is to copy and paste into the sd card of your device and with file manager install it.

but if you are on Windows phone 7 or higher you need developer unlocked device which means you need developer account and yearly 100$~.

Comment: I'm working on an application for a device running on Windows CE

Comment: check this out http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zcebx8f8(v=vs.80).aspx